# Main menu does not work on iOs

Tags: ios, css, wordpress, menu

My website http://basement-recordings.com/ is built on a free quill theme on wordpress (4.3.2).

I have a problem on all iphones on both chrome and safari: the main menu seems to work fine the first time I click the "hamburger", but the second time I click it everything is completely wrong.

Can anyone please help me figure this out? I have tried everything but it does not seem to work.

[image: this is ok]

[image: this is not]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

For some reason, the container's width of 100% only worked the first time I clicked on the menu.

Changing 100% to 100vw seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a floated `li` tags here

```
.main-navigation li {
  position: relative; 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
  -moz-border-radius: 75px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  float: left;
```

}
 so in your media queries you have to clear it from here using `float:none`

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 349px) and (max-width: 349px) and (min-device-width: 100px) and (orientation: portrait)
.main-navigation li {
height: 29vw;
width: 29vw;
line-height: 29vw;
-webkit-border-radius: 14.5vw;
-moz-border-radius: 14.5vw;
border-radius: 14.5vw;
margin-left: 2.2vw;
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 2.2vw;
display: block;
float: none;
}
```

and make sure the other media quires have the same fix, now I have this result.

[image]